# Pandas how to filter date time after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filter

Here is my original Table

```
A      Day-1
A      Day-2
A      Day-5
B      Day-3
B      Day-7
```

I would like to only keep the last several days.
For example, if I would like to keep last 4 days, then the table becomes

```
A      Day-2
A      Day-5
B      Day-7
```

For 'A', the last day is Day-5, and last 4 days would be Day2, Day3, Day4, Day5. Therefore, it's 'A Day-2' and 'A Day-5'

For 'B', the last day is Day-7, and last 4 days would be Day4, Day5, Day6, Day7. Therefore, it's 'B Day-7'

Here is what I tried:

```
df.groupby(['name']).tail(1)
```

And it shows the last day of each group, but how to filter date time according to this new dataframe?

```
A      Day-5
B      Day-7
```

Comment: what is your logic of keeping 2-5-7 day? last 3days looks 3-5-7

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo. It should be last 4 days
For 'A', the last day is Day-5, and last 4 days would be Day2, Day3, Day4, Day5. Therefore, it's 'A Day-2' and 'A Day-5'
For 'B', the last day is Day-7, and last 4 days would be Day4, Day5, Day6, Day7. Therefore, it's 'B Day-7'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'},
        'col2': {0: 'Day-1', 1: 'Day-2', 2: 'Day-5', 3: 'Day-3', 4: 'Day-7'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    col1    col2
0   A       Day-1
1   A       Day-2
2   A       Day-5
3   B       Day-3
4   B       Day-7
```

**Code**

```
s = df['col2'].str.split('-').str[-1].astype('int')
cond1 = s.groupby(df['col1']).transform(lambda x: x.gt(x.max()-4))
df[cond1]
```

result:

```
    col1    col2
1   A       Day-2
2   A       Day-5
4   B       Day-7
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the integer day value from the column then group by `name` and `transform` with `last` to broadcast the last day per `name` then compare current day with the last day to check where the difference is greater than `4`

```
day = df['day'].str.split('-').str[-1].astype(int)
mask = day > (day.groupby(df['name']).transform('last') - 4)

df[mask]
```

Result

```
  name    day
1    A  Day-2
2    A  Day-5
4    B  Day-7
```